# Maintain format of XML comment section on auto-formatting in Eclipse

Tags: xml, eclipse, pretty-print

In Eclipse (Helios) I have this XML source file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
I wanted to 
===========
save this format of the comments.

-->
<x>
</x>
```

On formatting the file (Ctrl+Shift+F) I got the comment reformatted.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- I wanted to =========== save this format of the comments. -->
<x>
</x>
```

Is there an option to switch off pretty-printing comment sections?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm using Eclipse 3.6.0.

In Windows > Preferences > XML > XML Files > Editor:

Uncheck the **Join lines** option.

Comment: You can also uncheck the whole "format comments" option, which looks quite useful, because the formatting of the comments happens always as clear text.

Answer (score 1):

You can select only part of your XML file for formatting and leave out the comment part.

Comment: but how can we format the comments just like normal lines??? that's the real question

Comment: PeterMmm originally asked "Is there an option to switch of pretty-print of comment sections ?". My answer is a workaround for this. @paul.cioroianu: If your questions is not covered you might want to create a new one.